# why is bash looking for vim in /usr/bin

Tags: 14.04, bash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

i compiled vim and installed in /usr/local/bin

i uninstalled the earlier versions of vim installed.

why is bash looking for vim in `/usr/bin` ?

```
vimal@Tardis:~/VIM/vim$ which -a vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
vimal@Tardis:~/VIM/vim$ vim
bash: /usr/bin/vim: No such file or directory

vimal@Tardis:~/VIM/vim$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/
total 3216
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Aug 10 11:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root    4096 Aug  9 11:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  972502 Aug  9 12:33 ctags
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       3 Aug  9 22:24 ex -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       3 Aug  9 22:24 rview -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       3 Aug  9 22:24 rvim -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       3 Aug  9 22:24 view -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2284512 Aug 10 11:39 vim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       3 Aug  9 22:24 vimdiff -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2084 Aug 10 11:39 vimtutor
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   18896 Aug 10 11:39 xxd
vimal@Tardis:~/VIM/vim$ id
uid=1001(vimal) gid=1001(vimal) groups=1001(vimal),4(adm),27(sudo),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
vimal@Tardis:~/VIM/vim$ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/vimal/gowork/bin
```

Comment: Run `hash -r` and then try again.

Comment: Show output of `echo $PATH`. In general, you just need to move in the variable the `/usr/local/bin` to be earlier than `/usr/bin`. But I'm asking the output because in my $PATH it *is* like this. But I can assume, though, that I swapped the order at some point of time, and just don't remember.

Comment: added `echo $PATH` output

Comment: Why did you compile vim? Why not install it a normal way?

Comment: `\vim` also returns the same result?

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the `bash` manual:

> Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files. A full search of the directories in PATH is performed only  if the command is not found in the hash table.

Here, what happened is that you:

1. removed the original `/usr/bin/vim`, and
2. created a new `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

In this case, `bash`'s path hash table was never updated, so when you call `vim` after 1 and 2, it finds the old hashed path. To force a path hash update, use `hash -r`.

AFAICT, `bash` has a strange and undocumented behavior, in that:

> If you call `vim` *between* 1 and 2 (leading to a legitimate "command not found"), then the hashed path is *automatically removed*, so when you call `vim` again after 2, it works just fine.

What I don't understand is why `bash` doesn't automatically remove the path when `vim` is called after 1 and 2 (as in your case), and the wrong path is found. But that's what's happening.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and this answer solved my problem. Did it solve your's too? If yes than mark it as best answer.

@weima